# How to return result set even with null condition in where in clause

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, where-clause, where-in

I am trying to chain multiple where-in clauses together, and am having issues when one of them returns `null`.

If the where in produces a `null` I would like to ignore it.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '
[
  {
    "key": "A",
     "value": ["1","2"]
  }, {
    "key": "B"
  }, , {
    "key": "C"
  }
]';

select *
from someTable]
where col1 in (select value from openjson(@json, '$[0].value'))
and col2 in (select value from openjson(@json, '$[0].value')) -- returns null, so empties query
and col3 in (select value from openjson(@json, '$[1].value')) -- returns null, so empties query
```

How would I omit the `where` from the result set when the set is null?

Comment: Maybe this will help you `and ( openjson(@json, '$[1].value') is null or col3 in (select value from openjson(@json, '$[1].value')))`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!